# Shared location for all python interpreters

Tags: development, python, directory

is there a shared location for all python interpreters? I want to install a module so it becomes avaiable to all interpreters (2.6, 2.7, 3.1).

Thanks you in advance,
rubik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the interpreters first look if there's an environment variable `$PYTHONPATH` set, which contains directories separated by `:`.

- To add a directory to it, type

  ```
  export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/home/stefano/my_modules"
  ```

Everything in this directory will now be available to all of your python interpreters. Non-existent directories are ignored without an error.

If you're happy with the settings, make the change permanent by appending the export command to the `.bashrc` file (or any other startup file you like in your home directory.

See also:

- [[image] § 6.1.2. The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)
- [[image] § 1.2. Environment variables](https://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

---

Note: the above syntax means that the variable PYTHONPATH will contain itself and the new path, you could also remove the `$PYTHONPATH:` part to just set one directory. Normally, this variable will be empty on your system, it makes sense to check if there's anything in it: `echo $PYTHONPATH`.